# How to loop through dates in Racket?

Tags: date, racket

I want to loop through dates from the current date to some stop date, like the following example in Python:

```
import datetime

def count_dates(stop_date):
    step = datetime.date.today()
    while step >= stop_date:
        yield step
        step = step - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

def main():
    for step in count_dates(datetime.date(2018, 1, 1)):
        print(step.isoformat())
```

I don't see any [date calculation functions](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/time.html) in Racket, however. How can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use `racket/date`, you can accomplish your goal with `find-seconds`, `seconds->date`, `current-seconds`, and a simple arithmetic:

```
#lang racket

(require racket/date
         racket/generator)

(define 1day (* 60 60 24))

(define (count-dates year month day)
  (define target (find-seconds 0 0 0 day month year))
  (in-generator
   (let loop ([current (current-seconds)])
     (when (>= current target)
       (yield (seconds->date current))
       (loop (- current 1day))))))

(date-display-format 'iso-8601)
(for ([dt (count-dates 2019 2 1)])
  (displayln (date->string dt)))
```

This outputs:

```
2019-02-11
2019-02-10
2019-02-09
2019-02-08
2019-02-07
2019-02-06
2019-02-05
2019-02-04
2019-02-03
2019-02-02
2019-02-01
```

That is, from today (Feb 11, 2019) to Feb 1, 2019.

You can also use [gregor](https://docs.racket-lang.org/gregor/index.html) or [srfi-19](https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-19/srfi-19.html) which are alternative date libraries that have a notion of time duration/difference.

Answer (score 4):

Here is how you can do it using the date arithmetic provided by [`gregor`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/gregor/index.html). Specifically the [`+days`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/gregor/date-arithmetic-provider.html#(def._((lib._gregor%2Fmain..rkt)._%2Bdays))) and [`-days`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/gregor/date-arithmetic-provider.html#%28def._%28%28lib._gregor%2Fmain..rkt%29._-days%29%29) functions are helpful here:

```
#lang racket

(require gregor
         racket/generator)

;; Date -> [Sequenceof Date]
(define (count-dates stop-date)
  (in-generator
   (let loop ([step (today)])
     (when (date>=? step stop-date)
       (yield step)
       (loop (-days step 1))))))

(for ([step (count-dates (date 2018 1 1))])
  (displayln (date->iso8601 step)))
```

And if you need something more general than "some number of days", there's also functions like [`+date-period`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/gregor/date-arithmetic-provider.html#%28def._%28%28lib._gregor%2Fmain..rkt%29._%2Bdate-period%29%29) and [`-date-period`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/gregor/date-arithmetic-provider.html#%28def._%28%28lib._gregor%2Fmain..rkt%29._-date-period%29%29).